# Doctrine2 in Symfony2 query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Doctrine in Symfony2. Here is the code:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeCrawlerBundle:Trainings');
$allActive = $repository->findByStatus('(Active)');
```

How can I take allByStatus WITH minimal `realId`? I mean, one row by status "(Active)" and minimal "realId".

Thank you!

Upd. I'm so stu... I can find just first and watch it's realId, cause i saved it in cycle... Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload the findByStatus function in your repository to use an orderby close in your query builder

```
<?php class TrainingsRepository { 
  /*other code here */
  public function findByStatus($status){
     $qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
     $qb->addWhere('t.status=:status');
     $qb->orderBy('idItem','ASC');
     $qb->setParameters(array(':status'=>$status));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
```